# React native bundleRelease task fails with error "The resource `index.js` was not found on a monorepo after upgrade from react-native 0.66.0 to 0.68.2

Tags: android, react-native, yarn-workspaces, metro-bundler, react-native-sentry

I have a mobile app and a web app for the same application and I use yarn workspaces monorepo to manage the two and the shared code in various packages. I have running this setup for a few months now successfully. I needed to make changes to same config files to get it work but it has been working very well till now.

Today, I updated from react-native 0.66.0 to 0.68.2. I made all the required changes and I am able to run the app in debug mode on iOS and Android. I am also able to build the iOS app successfully. But on Android, I am running into the following error:

```
warning: the transform cache was reset.
error The resource `/Users/username/Projects/myapp-monorepo/index.js` was not found.
Error: The resource `/Users/username/Projects/myapp-monorepo/index.js` was not found.
    at /Users/username/Projects/myapp-monorepo/node_modules/metro/src/IncrementalBundler.js:297:24
    at gotStat (node:fs:2654:21)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets_SentryUpload_com.myappapp@7.0.0+7340962_7340962 FAILED
  INFO    2022-05-30 19:23:40.400504 +05:30 Loaded config from /Users/username/.sentryclirc
  DEBUG   2022-05-30 19:23:40.401302 +05:30 sentry-cli version: 1.74.4, platform: "darwin", architecture: "x86_64"
  INFO    2022-05-30 19:23:40.401310 +05:30 sentry-cli was invoked with the following command line: "/Users/username/Projects/myapp-monorepo/node_modules/@sentry/cli/sentry-cli" "--log-level" "debug" "react-native" "gradle" "--bundle" "/Users/username/Projects/myapp-monorepo/packages/GalarmApp/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle" "--sourcemap" "/Users/username/Projects/myapp-monorepo/packages/GalarmApp/android/app/build/generated/sourcemaps/react/release/index.android.bundle.map" "--release" "com.myappapp@7.0.0+7340962" "--dist" "7340962"
error: An organization slug is required (provide with --org)
  DEBUG   2022-05-30 19:23:40.401360 +05:30 skipping update nagger because session is not attended

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets_SentryUpload_com.myappapp@7.0.0+7340962_7340962'.
> Process 'command '/Users/username/Projects/myapp-monorepo/node_modules/@sentry/cli/bin/sentry-cli'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

As you can see, it is trying to access `/Users/username/Projects/myapp-monorepo/index.js` and not finding it which of course the file is not there. The file is located in the app monorepo at location `/Users/username/Projects/myapp-monorepo/packages/myapp/index.js`.

I am not sure where is this coming from so I can fix the corresponding config file. It seems to be related to metro, Sentry and the release build task.

I am totally stuck due to this problem. If you have any pointers, please share.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the location where gradle/metro is looking for files. For e.g., I specify an `entryFile` in the build.gradle and specified an exact location and it went past that step but still gave some error further down the line. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did some more investigation. I removed the sentry integration from the project to figure out if it is something specific to Sentry but got the same error. So, I think it is related to some config issue in metro bundler. It is looking at the wrong location for the entry file.

Comment: Found the solution. Earlier I was setting the `reactRoot` to `../../../..` in `react.gradle` such that other places that use `reactRoot` are valid locations. But needed to set it back to `../../` and update the places that use `reactRoot` to have the extra `../../`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I have found the reason for the problem and not require any further answers but it could still be useful for other readers.

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is still looking for this answer

the error is

```
index.js file not found
```

this happens when we change the `index.js` file name to `index.jsx` or `index.tsx`

to resolve just change the name back to `index.js`